# Automatic form fill failproof

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

So, for a project I decided to build my own password manager. I build a simple html page and a chrome extension. They work together to perform a redirect and then fill in the form. This works on most sites. However, there are still some quirks. For example on iCloud.com it looks like this: https://www.dropbox.com/s/hwjxnb8igz1v8oy/Screenshot%202014-02-14%2021.29.46.png

My question is: How can I make this more reliable?

Below is my code that looks for type text and type password and then presses the submit button.

```
var username = request.username;
var password = request.password;
var node_list = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
var user_list = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
var submit_list = document.getElementsByTagName('button');
var textboxes = [];
var textboxxes = [];
var buttons = [];
for (var i = 0; i < node_list.length; i++) {
    var node = node_list[i];
    if (node.getAttribute('type') == 'password') {
        textboxes.push(node);
    }
} 
textboxes[0].value = password;
for (var i = 0; i < user_list.length; i++) {
    var user = user_list[i];
    if (user.getAttribute('type') == 'text') {
        textboxxes.push(user);
    }
} 
textboxxes[0].value = username;
for (var i = 0; i < submit_list.length; i++) {
    var submit = submit_list[i];
    if (submit.getAttribute('type') == 'submit') {
        buttons.push(submit);
    }
    else if (submit.getAttribute('role') == 'button') {
        buttons.push(submit);
    }
   } 

buttons[0].click();
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "more reliable"? There is a somewhat of a solution to the iCloud issue however I dont see what the problem is?

Comment: Well the problem is that it will not automatically click the 'submit' button. This is partially due to it not being a type=submit, but also because it doesn't notice that there has been something put in the fields.

Comment: Ok this isnt a complete answer however what you can do is figure out the URL that the form will POST/GET to and send that request manually, might be more work but it should work in theory.